# How can I remove inserted HTML in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have html that I insert into a webpage with my extension. The issue that I am having is figuring out how to remove all that html after the user hits the icon the second time around. I have the functionality for the clicking of the icon. Its the functionality for removing all inserted html that I am having issues with.

```
// This function toggles the extension on and fetches the required resources from the server.
function toggleExtOn(response) {
  document.getElementById('gic-wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", response);
}

//This function toggles the extension off.
function toggleExtOff() {
  document.getElementById("header").remove();
  document.getElementById("body").remove();
  document.getElementById("footer").remove();
}
```

In my html I have tags like such:

```
<head id='header'>
```

As you can see from the above code I attempt to give my head body and footer tags ids and remove it all that way. This does not work. What can I do to unload all the html that was inserted?

Comment: Your ids may be already used by the page, so it's best to put the UI inside iframe using `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: @wOxxOm this was perfect and exactly what I need. Thank you very much. If you want to post a full answer I'll accept it as the proper answer.